# VB.NET COM Server implementing Excel UDF not callable with optional Excel.Range

Tags: .net, excel, com

### Versions

Excel 2007 (12.0.6425.1000) SP2, Visual Studio 2008 with VB.NET, Windows Vista

### The windup

I have an Excel UDF written in VB.NET that has this signature:

```
Public Function NonExcelName(ByVal A As Integer, _
                        ByRef B As Range, ByRef C As Range, _
                        Optional ByVal D As Integer = 1, _
                        Optional ByVal E As Double = 0, _
                        Optional ByVal F As Range = Nothing, _
                        Optional ByVal G As Boolean = True, _
                        Optional ByVal H As Integer = 1) As Object
```

I had no trouble calling this in Excel with optional arguments like this:

```
=NonExcelName(99,$D$2:$D$65,$B$2:$B$65,12,,,,0)
```

for several months through last night. Now, it's a problem. Not sure why. The symptoms are:

> 1. required arguments only
>    If I provide all the required arguments and omit the optional ones, the function is callable: I will hit a breakpoint in the VB.NET debugger.
> 2. required arguments plus some optional
>    If I provide all the required arguments plus the optional ones up to optional Range G, the function is callable: I will hit a breakpoint in the VB.NET debugger.
> 3. required arguments plus optional through Range G
>    If I call the function with all the required arguments plus optional arguments including Range G, then I get *#VALUE!*. In this case, a break point at the first line of code in the debugger is not hit: the function simply is not called.
> 4. all parameters
>    Works.
> 5. all parameters except optional parameter G
>    Does not work.

I can't identify any Windows updates that might have caused this. I have other COM Servers implemented in the same way that do not have optional Ranges and are not exhibiting this problem.

I have experimented with `Optional ByVal F As Range = Nothing` to no effect.

I have not rolled my source code back to last night yet. I'm trying that next.

---

### The pitch

Is there some rule of COM/.NET interaction that I am violating? Is there something in the Windows universe that has changed? What would explain why Excel/COM refuses to call this function with a comma-separated optional parameter?

---

Edit 2009-10-07: Changing Integer arguments to Double does not help. Changing `Optional ByVal F As Range = Nothing` to `Optional ByRef F As Range = Nothing` does not help.

---

Edit 2009-10-10: I changed the UDF from *DB* to *NonExcelName* to underline the fact that it is not clashing with an Excel function name. The real name is for custom software to be released on teh web, so I did not want to give the name away.

---

Edit 2009-10-11: I've run Mike's code and I get much the same results as with my own code: it fails when I omit the optional Range argument with a comma.

[alt text http://www.iwebthereforeiam.com/files/MyDb%20fail.gif](http://www.iwebthereforeiam.com/files/MyDb%20fail.gif)

I can put in the mandatory arguments and I am fine, but once I omit the optional argument with a comma (either putting in the rest of the arguments or not), the function call generates a *#VALUE!*.

Edit 2009-10-11: Maybe it's like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168290/how-to-pass-a-late-bound-parameter): maybe my optional Range is being passed as a String instead of as Nothing. How would I go about testing/confirming this? I don't seem to hit a breakpoint inside my code.

---

Edit 2009-10-12: Wow. The fix was in two parts.

(1) Use of VB.NET IIf() statement

This does not short-circuit like the ternary operator in C/C++/C#. You cannot write code like this and expect it to work in VB/VBA/VB.NET:

```
Return IIf(optRange Is Nothing, "<No Range Provided>", optRange.Address)
```

VB/VBA/VB.NET seems to evaluate both expressions, causing an exception when the argument *optRange* is Nothing. You have to write it like this:

```
If optRange Is Nothing Then
    Return "<No Range Provided>"
Else
    Return optRange.Address
End If
```

(2) Use of optional Object instead of optional Range

I don't quite know what the problem is, but I can't get any function to take optional Ranges anymore. I am passsing optional Objects and it works. This does not work:

```
Function OptionalRange2(Optional ByVal optRange1 As Excel.Range = Nothing, Optional ByVal optRange2 As Excel.Range = Nothing) As Object
```

and this does:

```
Function OptionalRange3(Optional ByVal optRange1 As Object = Nothing, Optional ByVal optRange2 As Object = Nothing) As Object
```

---

Edit 2009-10-12: I've explored the multiple Range parsing hypothesis. Interesting, but not the cause, as far as I can tell. This function signature should not have that problem because it has an integer in the middle:

```
Function OptionalRange4(Optional ByVal optRange1 As Excel.Range = Nothing, _
                        Optional ByVal optInt As Integer = 0, _
                        Optional ByVal optRange2 As Excel.Range = Nothing) As Object _
    Implements IFunctions.OptionalRange4
```

And yet it produces *#VALUE!* for `=OptionalRange4(,12,)`.

I have a fix (declare optional Object, not Range, and cast the argument) but I don't know why I have the problem.

Comment: Ok I took another look at this, Hugh. My updated answer is below. Hope this does the trick...

Comment: Hugh, I promise you that this absolutely *is* an issue with how Excel handles Range parameters, especially multiple-area Ranges and optional parameters. I agree that placing an optional non-Range parameter between the two optional Range parameters, should disambiguate, but Excel, unfortunately, still cannot interpret this and throws a #VALUE! error without calling your function.

I'll elevate this to a discussion among the Excel MVPs, and hopefully someone is able to explain this more precisely. I'll reply back again if I get a more precise answer to this.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer again to explain the quirky behavior regarding optional Range parameters. It does seem to be a bug, at least when called from .NET. See below. (It's my 9th revision though, so it's now a "Community Wiki", lol. Ugh, if you work too hard on an answer, you lose ownership of it. Pretty odd...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer Regarding Optional Range Parameters**

Ok, after discussing the issue with some Excel MVPs, there's a couple of points I can add to this quirky issue regarding optional Range parameters when used in a user-defined function (UDF) created using VB.NET.

(1) The first is that this appears to be some sort of subtle issue regarding how Excel calls the .NET user-defined function; the issue cannot be replicated using VBA. For example, the following function written in VBA does not exhibit the same problem:

```
Function OptionalRange4(Optional ByVal optRange1 As Excel.Range = Nothing, _
                        Optional ByVal optInt As Integer = 0, _
                        Optional ByVal optRange2 As Excel.Range = Nothing) _
                        As Variant
    Dim arg1 As String
    Dim arg2 As String
    Dim arg3 As String

    If optRange1 Is Nothing Then
        arg1 = "<Nothing>"
    Else
        arg1 = optRange1.Address
    End If

    arg2 = CStr(optInt)

    If optRange2 Is Nothing Then
        arg3 = "<Nothing>"
    Else
        arg3 = optRange2.Address
    End If

    OptionalRange4 = arg1 + "|" + arg2 + "|" + arg3
End Function
```

(2) The other information I learned is that you can pass in multi-area ranges into a single parameter of a worksheet function by enclosing the entire range address in brackets. For example, the following formula will pass in two Range arguments to the "MyFunction", the first argument being a multi-area address:

```
=MyFunction((A1:C3,D4:E5), G11)
```

So the two solutions available to you would appear to be:

(a) Change your parameter types from Range to Object and then cast the Object to a Range within your code. This would seem to be the cleanest and easiest approach.

(b) Create a VBA wrapper as your front-end, which then calls your Visual Basic.NET code. I'm sure that this is not what you would want, but I thought that I should mention it. For what it's worth, this approach is mandatory if wishing to use UDFs from VSTO, at least as of Visual Studio 2008. The article [How to create Excel UDFs in VSTO managed code](http://blogs.msdn.com/pstubbs/archive/2004/12/31/344964.aspx) by Paul Stubbs describes this very approach.

That's all I can add Hugh. It is a subtle bug or flaw in how the Excel call tries to work it's way through the .NET Interop. I don't know why exactly it fails, but it does. Fortunately, the solution to it is not too onerous.

-- Mike

**Prior Answer Regarding Optional Range Parameters**

> I still don't know why I can't get
>   this to work:
>
> ```
> Function OptionalRange2(Optional ByVal optRange1 As Excel.Range =
> ```
>
> Nothing, _
>                               Optional ByVal optRange2 As Excel.Range =
>   Nothing) As Object _
>           Implements IFunctions.OptionalRange2
>
> Both =OptionalRange2(E2:E7,F2:F7) 
>   First =OptionalRange2(E2:E7,)
>   Second =OptionalRange2(,F2:F7)
>   Neither =OptionalRange2()
>   Neither with comma =OptionalRange2(,)
>
> [Calls to Both and Neither are successful.] Putting
>   in the comma changes the call. It's as
>   if with no comma, Excel sends two
>   Nothings but with the comma it does
>   something else --
>
> •send
>   System.Type.Missing/System.Reflection.Missing.Value?
>
> •call Range.Value(), the default
>   function on Range, passing a parameter
>   of a different type?
>
> Either way, it's
>   like there is a type mismatch at
>   runtime because it just does not get
>   into the debugger's stack frame.

What's happening here is that Excel can get confused when passing in range arguments. The reason is that a range address can include a comma in it, such as the multi-area address "A1:C3, D4:E5". When you pass in such an address as a range argument, Excel has to make a determination as to whether this is a single multi-area range or consists of two single-area range arguments.

So the question is: which way does Excel interpret it?

The answer is that Excel always interprets the comma as an argument separator, so there is actually no way to pass in a multi-area range into a single parameter in Excel directly. To do that, you'd have to pass in a named range (such as defining a multi-area range named "MyRange") and then passing that into your user-defined worksheet function.

So, in these examples, when you pass in MyFunction(A1:C3, D4:E5), you are using up both parameters, not just one.

Ok, but where's the problem?

The problem is: how does Excel interpret the range address "A1:C3," when passed into a worksheet function? The answer is that Excel attempts to interpret this as a single range address with invalid syntax, since the final part of the address following the comma is missing. In short, it's a syntax error, so your function is never called in the first place, and a #VALUE results.

This is very unfortunate since I already said that Excel is supposed to give precedence to interpreting the comma as an argument separator, not as an area separator within a range address. But, alas, Excel is inconsistent here and it attempts to interpret a leading or trailing comma as part of the range address itself.

You hit on the solution yourself earlier: change the data type for these optional parameters from Range to Object and then cast the Object to Range within your code. If you do this, then Excel will no longer attempt to interpret the arguments as a Range and everything will work fine.

You can test the difference between the two approaches with the following user-defined functions:

```
Function DualOptionalRanges(Optional ByVal optRange1 As Excel.Range = Nothing, _
                            Optional ByVal optRange2 As Excel.Range = Nothing) _
                            As Object _
    Implements IFunctions.DualOptionalRanges

    Dim arg1 As String = If(optRange1 IsNot Nothing, optRange1.Address, "<Nothing>")
    Dim arg2 As String = If(optRange2 IsNot Nothing, optRange2.Address, "<Nothing>")

    Return arg1 + "|" + arg2
End Function

Function DualOptionalVariants(Optional ByVal optVariant1 As Object = Nothing, _
                              Optional ByVal optVariant2 As Object = Nothing) _
                              As Object _
    Implements IFunctions.DualOptionalVariants

    Dim range1 As Excel.Range

    Try
        range1 = CType(optVariant1, Excel.Range)
    Catch ex As Exception
        range1 = Nothing
    End Try

    Dim range2 As Excel.Range

    Try
        range2 = CType(optVariant2, Excel.Range)
    Catch ex As Exception
        range2 = Nothing
    End Try


    Dim arg1 As String
    If range1 IsNot Nothing Then
        arg1 = range1.Address
    Else
        arg1 = If(optVariant1 IsNot Nothing, optVariant1.ToString(), "<Nothing>")
    End If

    Dim arg2 As String
    If range2 IsNot Nothing Then
        arg2 = range2.Address
    Else
        arg2 = If(optVariant2 IsNot Nothing, optVariant2.ToString(), "<Nothing>")
    End If

    Return arg1 + "|" + arg2
End Function
```

I think this should be the last hurdle. (Famous last words, right?)

-- Mike

**Answer Regarding IIF**

Bummer about the IIF ("immediate if") issue. I believe that other than the CType() and DirectCast() operators, and new functionality given to the IF keyword, everything that utilizes method syntax in VB.NET is, in fact, a method call that is executed at run-time. CType() and DirectCast() are the exceptions; they are casting mechanisms that are evaluated at compile-time, and the IF keyword can now be utilized as an operator using a method-like syntax, but it uses short-circuit evaluation instead of evaluating all parameters before evaluating the IF operator.

The lack of a short-circuit capability for IIF was discussed at length by Paul Vic in 2006 in the article [IIF, a True Ternary Operator and Backwards Compatibility](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2006/12/29/18883.aspx). The article shows a strong leaning towards changing IIF to use short-circuit evaluation as of VB.NET 2009. However, due to backwards-compatibility issues, they decided not to change the behavior of IIF and to simply extend how the IF keyword can be used, allowing it to be utilized as an operator. This is described in [IIF becomes If, and a true ternary operator](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2007/05/08/20433.aspx), also by Paul Vick.

Sorry you got snagged on this.

-- Mike

**Answer Regarding Naming Conflicts**

Hi Hugh,

I think you have a naming conflict with Excel's built-in 'DB' worksheet function. If you rename your user-defined function from "DB" to "MyDb" (or almost anything else) I think you'll be fine.

It was tough to know what might be going wrong with your add-in, because your code looks clean. So I created an automation add-in using VB.NET and experimented with your user-defined function (UDF) using the same exact parameter signature you described. I found no problems.

The automation add-in I used was defined as follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Text
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("7F1A3650-BEE4-4751-B790-3A527195C7EF")> _
Public Interface IFunctions
    ' * User-Defined Worksheet Functions Definitions *
    Function MyDb(ByVal A As Integer, _
                ByRef B As Excel.Range, _
                ByRef C As Excel.Range, _
                Optional ByVal D As Integer = 1, _
                Optional ByVal E As Double = 0, _
                Optional ByVal F As Excel.Range = Nothing, _
                Optional ByVal G As Boolean = True, _
                Optional ByVal H As Integer = 1) As Object

    Function OptionalBoolean(Optional ByVal optBoolean As Boolean = False) As Object

    Function OptionalDouble(Optional ByVal optDouble As Double = 0.0) As Object

    Function OptionalInteger(Optional ByVal optInteger As Integer = 0) As Object

    Function OptionalRange(Optional ByVal optRange As Excel.Range = Nothing) As Object

    Function OptionalVariant(Optional ByVal optVariant As Object = Nothing) As Object
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("FCC8DC2F-4B44-4fb6-93B5-769E57A908A1")> _
<ProgId("VbOptionalParameters.Functions")> _
<ComDefaultInterface(GetType(IFunctions))> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
Public Class Functions
    Implements IFunctions

    ' * User-Defined Worksheet Functions */
    Function MyDb(ByVal A As Integer, _
                ByRef B As Excel.Range, _
                ByRef C As Excel.Range, _
                Optional ByVal D As Integer = 1, _
                Optional ByVal E As Double = 0, _
                Optional ByVal F As Excel.Range = Nothing, _
                Optional ByVal G As Boolean = True, _
                Optional ByVal H As Integer = 1) As Object _
            Implements IFunctions.MyDb

        Return "MyDb Successfully called"
    End Function

    Function OptionalBoolean(Optional ByVal optBoolean As Boolean = False) As Object _
        Implements IFunctions.OptionalBoolean

        Return optBoolean.ToString()
    End Function

    Function OptionalDouble(Optional ByVal optDouble As Double = 0.0) As Object _
        Implements IFunctions.OptionalDouble

        Return optDouble.ToString()
    End Function

    Function OptionalInteger(Optional ByVal optInteger As Integer = 0) As Object _
        Implements IFunctions.OptionalInteger

        Return optInteger.ToString()
    End Function

    Function OptionalRange(Optional ByVal optRange As Excel.Range = Nothing) As Object _
        Implements IFunctions.OptionalRange

        If optRange Is Nothing Then
            Return "<No Range Provided>"
        Else
            Return optRange.Address
        End If
    End Function

    Function OptionalVariant(Optional ByVal optVariant As Object = Nothing) As Object _
        Implements IFunctions.OptionalVariant

        If optVariant Is Nothing Then
            Return "<No Argument Provided>"
        Else
            Return optVariant.ToString()
        End If
    End Function

    ' * automation add-in Registration *
    <ComRegisterFunctionAttribute()> _
    Public Shared Sub RegisterFunction(ByVal type As Type)
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey( _
          GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"))

        Dim key As RegistryKey = _
            Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey( _
              GetSubKeyName(type, "InprocServer32"), _
              True)

        key.SetValue( _
          String.Empty, _
          System.Environment.SystemDirectory + "\mscoree.dll", _
          RegistryValueKind.String)
    End Sub

    <ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute()> _
Public Shared Sub UnregisterFunction(ByVal type As Type)
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey( _
          GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"), _
          False)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetSubKeyName(ByVal type As Type, ByVal subKeyCategory As String) As String
        Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("CLSID\{")
        sb.Append(type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper())
        sb.Append("}\")
        sb.Append(subKeyCategory)
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function

End Class
```

Using the above, one can test for individual optional parameters such as Booleans, Doubles, Integers, Ranges, or any Variant via the 'OptionalBoolean', 'OptionalDouble', 'OptionalInteger', 'OptionalRange', and 'OptionalVariant' functions. And the complete function signature in question can be tested via the 'MyDb' function. None of the above failed in my testing, unless passing in an obviously incompatible argument type, such as passing in a string into an integer or double parameter, passing a numeric value into a range parameter, or the like.

There are problems, however, when naming the main user-defined function "DB", because this conflicts with Excel's built-in "DB" worksheet function, which stands for "Declining Balance" and has existed since at least Excel '97. Basically, because the user-defined function in your automation add-in has the same name as Excel's built-in version, your UDF is ignored.

In my testing using Excel 2007, I could not get Excel to recognize your 'DB' user-defined function at all. I'm not sure why you seemed to get erratic behavior, where your call sometimes came through and sometimes did not. It is possible that earlier versions of Excel handle this naming conflict differently.

The bottom line is, though, that you should be able to rename your UDF and then have no problems. I don't see anything else that could be causing this.

I hope this does it for you Hugh, fingers crossed....

Mike

**Answer Regarding Optional Data Types**

With this amount of information, I can only guess, but I do not think that you are not violating any COM Interop rules.

My guess is that the problem has to do with what arguments you are providing to your function. If the arguments passed into the user-defined function (UDF) do not match the expected parameter types, then Excel will throw a #VALUE! error without ever calling your code at all.

So in your third scenario, which is failing, you are passing in one of the parameters incorrectly. For example, the signature for the 'F' parameter is:

```
Optional ByVal F As Range = Nothing
```

With this signature, if you pass it a value directly, such as a string "Hello", then a #VALUE! error will result without your code ever getting called.  If you passed in a cell reference that held the value "Hello", however, then the 'F' parameter would accept this with no problem.

What you need to do is to try calling your UDF while very carefully considering the parameter types being passed in. Change the parameters one at a time and see which force your UDF to at least be called. You can either set a breakpoint, or have your UDF return "Success" or the like just for debugging purposes. The key for now is just to figure out what the correct parameter types are. I have a feeling that if you do this you will figure out what is wrong very quickly.

Actually, I *think* I might see the problem:

I'm a bit suspicious of your 'Integer' parameters, which are parameter's 'A', 'D', and 'H'. If you pass an integer value into the function directly, then these parameters should work fine. But if you pass in a cell reference, then Excel will automatically pass in the Range.Value for that cell, automatically -- which is what you want...

... but the problem is that Excel cells can never hold an 'Integer' data type! They can hold "Integer" values, such as 0, 1, 2, -1, etc., of course, but these are actually typed as 'Double' when held by the cell. To prove this, you can assign an Integer to the Cell.Value, but it will be stored as a Double -- if you check the data type held by the Cell.Value via TypeName() or .GetType().ToString(), it will return "Double".

Cells can holds Booleans, Strings, Double, Date, Currency (which translates to Decimal in .NET), and CVErr values, and that's it. Under standard usage they cannot return an 'Integer'. (If directly accessing the XLOPER via a C++ XLL then you technically *could* access integer values, but this is a very non-standard, and you can't do this from VB.NET or C#.)

Therefore, I would focus on these Integer parameters first, particularly with respect to passing in an Integer value directly versus passing in a cell reference that holds a numeric value. I'm guessing that the non-optional 'A' parameter might be able to accept a cell reference -- but maybe not, I'm not sure -- but I'm even less sure that the optional parameters can accept a cell reference holding a Double data type.

So, overall, I'm guessing here, but I think you should be able to start with a working set of parameters and then change each parameter one by one to see which call works or fails for each parameter.

Good luck, Hugh, let us know how this goes...

Mike

Comment: It's not actually named 'DB'. I'm sorry for misleading you. It's custom software for a client who is releasing it on the web and I didn't want to use the real name. I'll change that. That said, I think your approach is productive and I was planning to do something like this: create a new UDF with different signatures and see which cause problems. I will check this out.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I don't know, then, because I had no problems in my testing. Good luck tracking it down, hopefully my template can help you.

Comment: On IF/IIF: I found the solution (global search and replace IIF() with IF()). You are the one-stop shop for solution history, though. I think you've linked to the same web page twice, no? I think you meant this for the second link: http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2007/05/08/20433.aspx

Comment: Yes, my 2nd link was a typo, good picup. The link's title was right though, so partial credit, lol. I've now fixed it, above -- thanks for head's up.

Comment: Re: Excel passes multiple ranges when comma-separated. Okay, I am willing to believe that that is a plausible explanation. Now why do you not see it on your machine? Why should it be a problem unique to my development world?

Comment: I can duplicate all your issues 100%. The only one that I could not duplicate originally was the IIF issue, because this dealt with an internal implementaition that you had not disclosed in your question, so I couuld only test the method signatures. Once you reported the IIF issue, I could duplicate it and every other issue you've discussed here.